# Crystal Report Remove Embedded Printer

Tags: crystal-reports

Using Crystal Report XI.

When I save the report, the default printer which is installed on my machine is being set as the default printer of the report, so that the deployed reports when printed goes to my default printer.

How would I be able to remove the default printer so that when they print the report, it would default to the user's default printer.

By the way, I cannot have the option of displaying a printer dialog window since some of these process are automated (i.e., no human intervention).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Do not set a printer for your report, and it will automatically get set to the default printer on the end user's cpu.

Answer (score 0):

If you're good with scripting, you could write a script to open the .rpt, change the printer, save the .rpt, then print it.

Answer (score 0):

To disassociate a printer from your report:

- Open the report file in Crystal Reports.
- From the "File" menu, pick "Page Setup...".
- At the top of the Page Setup dialog, check the "No Printer" checkbox.
- OK.
- Save the report file.

Comment: Using the “no printer” checkbox leads to different behavior/results than not checking it but not having a printer set within the rpt. There is a difference between rpt being for printing but no printer set within the rpt, and the rpt being marked not for printing (but for displaying only).